# Memoir page headers and minipage

Tags: header-footer, memoir, minipage

I'm trying to work with a custom pagestyle. I want to have the chapter name and the section name in the odd page header... but I also need to use a mini page environment (or WANT to use one anyway) and latex is not recognizing a section in the minipage... I tried it with parbox as well and it also won't work. Any ideas other than abandoning the minipage.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir} 

\usepackage{lipsum}
\makepagestyle{teststyle}
\makeoddhead{teststyle}{}{\leftmark * \rightmark}{\thepage} 
\makeevenhead{teststyle}{\thepage}{ book name}{}
\makepsmarks{teststyle}{%
\createmark{chapter}{both} {nonumber}{ }{. \ }
\createmark{section}{right} {nonumber}{ }{. \ }}

\pagestyle{teststyle}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Name of Chapter}


\noindent\begin{minipage}[t][][b]{0.25\textwidth}
\small This is on the Left
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b][][t]{.5\textwidth}
\section{Name of Section}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t][][b]{0.25\textwidth}
\hfill \small This is on the right
\end{minipage}



\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum

\section{Non Minipage Section}
\lipsum
\lipsum


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `\section` is getting "trapped" inside the minipage, and therefore its marking information doesn't, as it were, get out.  Although I wouldn't be surprised by some wizardly solutions, the simplest thing to do is probably to use the `\markright` command, which is what `\rightmark` contains in a normal document. In essence, your document is using:

```
\markboth{<main mark>}{<sub mark>}
\markright{<sub mark>}
```

where

```
\leftmark{} 
\rightmark{}
```

respectively contain the most recent `<main mark>` and `<sub mark>` text.  Thus, if you want this line ---

```
\makeoddhead{teststyle}{}{\leftmark{} * \rightmark}{\thepage}% Note the difference the added "{}" makes
```

--- to work normally, all you need add is:

```
\markright{Name of Section}%  where "Name of Section" == the section title in the minipage
```

If you want the `\rightmark` to be upper-cased as is the default in `memoir`, then ---

```
\markright{\MakeUppercase{Name of Section}}
```

--- should do the trick.